# OS X: Focus but only raise windows when clicked on titlebar?

Tags: macos, window, focus

You can move windows while maintaining Z-order by holding command. Is it possible to get a window to have focus but not raising it?

I thought OS X was supposed to support drag and drop but how can you support it when you keep raising windows and obscuring the target window? Also I hoped to drag and drop between expose'd windows, not possible?

I am not talking about FFM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35820182/1741533 ⌃⌥-click (control-option-click) - switches focus without raising window

⌘-click (command-click) - clicks in window without switching focus

Not sure when these shortcuts were introduced, as I haven't been able to find them written about anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

⌃⌥-click (control-option-click) - switches focus without raising window

⌘-click (command-click) - clicks in window without switching focus

Not sure when these shortcuts were introduced, as I haven't been able to find them written about anywhere.