# Turn Off Auto-Focus in Terminal OS X

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

Based on these 2 SO questions:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98310/focus-follows-mouse-plus-auto-raise-on-mac-os-x)

[Link 2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-make-focus-follow-the-mouse-cursor)

It seems I have enabled this on my Mac as well. I am not sure how I even enabled this, but I certainly didn't want it. How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these 3 commands did the trick. I tried all 3, but didn't close and re-open the terminal app, so i'm not sure which one worked. Guess it had to restart for new changes to take effect. I just changed `true` to `false`, the number `1` to `2` and `yes` to `no`.

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse -bool false

defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse -string 2

defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse -string NO
```

Answer (score 2):

This was also enabled for me seemingly by default. For some reason, the answers around the web that all used `-bool false` didn't work for me. This is the command that successfully turned it off:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse -string NO
```

Then restart Terminal.app for it to take effect.

Tested on macOS 10.14.4.

Answer (score 1):

It's the first one in Kervvv's answer, at least in El Capitan - just tested. Run it then quit Terminal and reopen.

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse -bool false
```