# focus follows mouse (NO autoraise) in Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, focus, mouse

I'm aware of the other threads on this topic but they are autoraised-based and/or all the answers point to software that's no longer being developed. I'm just looking for this simple feature: focus follows mouse WITHOUT autoraise for Mac. 
Zooom2 was able to perform this, but they are no longer developing their software. 
I'm not using the terminal and need to copy/paste and read between multiple programs with multiple windows, someone please tell you've found a solution to this?

Comment: Have you found a good solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

[chunkwm](https://koekeishiya.github.io/chunkwm/docs/source.html) has recently added a setting ffm_disable_autoraise which works well for me on macOS Mojave.  To enable only the Focus Follows Mouse feature, follow the install steps then edit `~/.chunkwmrc` to comment out undesired plugins and enable FFM

```sh
# chunkc core::load border.so
# chunkc core::load tiling.so
chunkc core::load ffm.so
```

and disable autoraise

```sh
chunkc set ffm_disable_autoraise         1
```

The other available plugins are useful but are not the subject of this question.

**Edit** 2019-09-12:

chunkwm has been superseded by [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai).  To install:

```sh
brew tap koekeishiya/formulae
brew install yabai
mkdir -p ~/.config/yabai/
printf 'yabai -m config focus_follows_mouse autofocus' >> ~/.config/yabai/yabairc
brew services start yabai
```

Comment: Yabai works wonderfully! Thank you for solving my biggest gripe with macOS.

Comment: This is a lifesaver

Comment: Can this be configured to move focus over to other displays with mouse?

Comment: The above configuration works nicely with multiple displays.

Answer (score 0):

I do miss one thing in `Yabai` - the ability to focus to a subwindow within a focussed window. That would be gold!

Comment: Focus between applications is controlled by the window manager or Yabai. Focus between panes in an application is controlled by that application. For example, Visual Studio Code has a feature request to add this ability; https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93772. Contact the developer of the application you have in mind.

Answer (score -1):

I am using [AutoRaise](https://github.com/sbmpost/AutoRaise). The modified fork from fredngo works well for me. Check out at https://github.com/sbmpost/AutoRaise/issues/47#issuecomment-1129157693.